# Calculate area under curve using integral

Tags: calculus, area

Hello I am having problem with this easy one:

$\int_{-2}^2(x+2)dx = [\frac{x^2}{2}+2x]_{-2}^2 = (\frac{4}{2}+4) - (\frac{-4}{2}-4) = (6)+(6)=12$

but according to the solutions manual the correct answer is 8. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $$(-2)^2 = 4{}{}{}$$

Answer (score 1):

As you were told in the comments, $(-2)^2=4$. Besides, did you try to think about *which* area you were computing? It's the area of a triangle whose vertices are $(-2,0)$, $(2,0)$, and $(2,4)$. It's half a square whose side is $4$. Therefore, its area is $8$. You don't need a solution manual to tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

Differently perhaps:

Note: f(x):= x is an odd function, hence the integral from -2 to +2 is 0.

Left: the integral from -2 to +2 of g(x) :=2.

You calculate the area of a rectangle: length 4; height: 2, which is?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-2}^2(x+2) \ dx=\int_{-2}^2x \ dx+\int_{-2}^22 \ dx=\bigg[\frac {x^2}{2}\bigg]_{-2}^2+\bigg[2x\bigg]_{-2}^2$$

$$=\bigg(\frac {2^2}{2}-\frac {(-2)^2}{2}\bigg)+\bigg(2(2)-2(-2)\bigg)=8$$